# OpenCL tasks hang at submitted

Tags: opencl

Ich have a strange problem. I just started with openCL development and implemented a simple matrix multiplication:

```
void MatrixMult(float *M, float *N, float *P, int width) {
    cl_context context = core.getContext();
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = core.getCommandQueue();

    // create the kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = core.createKernel("MatrixMultKernel");

    // reserve memory for i/o
    int size = width * width * sizeof(float);
    cl_mem Md = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size, M, NULL);
    cl_mem Nd = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size, N, NULL);
    cl_mem Pd = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , size, NULL, NULL);

    // define kernel args
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &Md);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &Nd);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &Pd);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(int), &width);

    // create kernel instances
    size_t globalSize[] = {static_cast<size_t>(width), static_cast<size_t>(width)};
    cl_int kernelError = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (kernelError != CL_SUCCESS) {
        NSLog(@"Error executing kernel");
    }

    // read back results
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, Pd, false, 0, size, P, 0, NULL, &readEvent);
    clSetEventCallback(readEvent, CL_COMPLETE, &eventCallback, NULL);
}
```

My problem is that the callback is never called. I test with small inputs which should finish immediately.

The strange this is whenever I call the function (MatrixMult) a second time the callback fires as it should. The same thing for every consecutive call. When I check the event while it is not firing it always has the status CL_SUBMITTED. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add a call to clFlush at the end of your code. Though the OpenCL spec may not clearly list that as a requirement, I find it is the case on my system. It is waiting for either clFlush of a command that does an implicit clFlush.